# How to completely disable the Xsession Errors?

Tags: ubuntu

There is lots of question all around different forums but nobody has the right solution.

I tried the following things on Debian based system:

1. in dir /etc/X11/ commented `"ERRFILE=$HOME/.xsession-errors"` the Xsesssion file. Unfortunately did not solved my issues.
2. Also replaced `exec >>"$ERRFILE" 2>&1` to `exec >> /dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: @DenishParvadia: when editing, please only use quote blocks for quotes - it is not a general highlighter. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In current version the `Xsession` script **will use `tempfile` if `~/.xsession-errors`** was inaccessible for any reason or **is a symlink to /dev/null** and thus litter in `/tmp` if you try to block writing to the default filename.

Changing the line to `exec >> /dev/null 2>&1` as you did *almost* worked: the file was still created by the code above but wasn't written to. Changing a line higher in the script where `ERRFILE` is set should've been good unless the target is a symlink (pay attention to **all** the checks that are performed with that variable).

I've written a patch for the upstream of `/etc/X11/Xsession`:

https://salsa.debian.org/xorg-team/xorg/-/merge_requests/7

If you apply the patch and set `NOXSESSIONERRORS` environment variable either for your user or system-wide all stderr will be redirected to `/dev/null`. You will have to re-apply the patch after every `x11-common` package update until it is merged and published.

More info: https://askubuntu.com/a/212311/20275

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option that doesn't involve a patch. I put the code into a separate file, so it won't be overwritten when packages are updated.

```
# echo '# redirect all output to null and delete error file
exec >>/dev/null 2>&1
rm "$ERRFILE"
' > /etc/X11/Xsession.d/01disable.xsession-errors
```